# do_trucate in jinja2, correct usage needed

Tags: flask, jinja2

I think I saw something on using this to truncate test as a filter, but I've seen to no idea how to use it. Using as `xx|do_trucate(20)` gives the following:

```
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'do_truncate'
```

What is the correct usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, from the spec I saw

```
do_trucate

http://code.nabla.net/doc/jinja2/api/jinja2/jinja2.filters.html
```

But in reality, its just `truncate`